# How to reset 2FA on the phpmyadmin software?

Tags: mysql, php, apache2, xampp, phpmyadmin

I have been using 2FA (2 factor authentication) to log in into the admin panel but I recently resettled my phone which has the 2FA code due to certain problems. I tried reading through the phpmyadmin documentation but it only show the method to activate 2FA. How do I disable it possibly without doing a re-installation?

I use XAMPP to host the server currently

Comment: What do other products do in this situation?  (I suspect this is a generic issue with 2FA).

Comment: They are products that comes with XAMPP. 2FA is set using the PHPMYADMIN admin panel that deals with the sql